# Django выдаёт ошибку: can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str

Tags: python, django

сегодня столкнулся с такой проблемой: при попытке отправке письма через SEND_EMAIL Django выдаёт ошибку. Она заключается в том, что он не может соединить str с NoneType, но я не смог найти NoneType строк у себя в коде. Даже если заполнить строки с пробелами текстом, всё равно выдаёт ошибку.

views.py

```
def send_email(request):
    subject = 'Заявка на консультацию'
    message = 'Имя:' + ' ' + request.POST.get('name_field') + '\n' + 'Номер:' + ' ' + 
    request.POST.get('number_field') + '\n' + 'Почта:' + ' ' +  request.POST.get('mail_field')
    email_from = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
    recipient_list = ['MoyaPochta@gmail.com']
    send_mail(subject, message, email_from, recipient_list)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/form/')
```

Ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы зачем-то конкатерируете `request.POST.get('name_field')` (которая скорее всего возвращает None) со строками... [дока django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/email/#preventing-header-injection)

Comment: Добавьте ошибку текстом (скрин не нужен).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать f строки или

> .format

```
message = "Имя: {name} \nНомер: {phone} \nПочта: {email}".format(name=request.get('name_field'), phone=request.get('number_field'), email=request.get('mail_field'))
```

Это будет более корректным решением, чем просто конкатенировать строки и вероятнее всего решит Вашу проблему

Comment: хоть бы пример дали